# dynamic meta showing repeated tags in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic, meta-tags

I have created a php code for showing Meta tags on dynamic pages. The code is something like :

```
<?php  }?>
<?php if(isset($store_det)) {?>
<title>"This is an example text"</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="This,is">
<meta name="description" content="This is an example text">
<?php } if(isset($popular_store)) {  ?>  
<title>"This is an example text"</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="This,is">
<meta name="description" content="This is an example text">
<?php } if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'aboutus') {  ?>  
<title>"This is an example text"</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="This,is">
<meta name="description" content="This is an example text">
<?php } else {  ?>
<title>"This is an example text"</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="This,is">
<meta name="description" content="This is an example text">
<?php } ?>
```

The issue is its showing meta twice on 2 variable i defined above $store and $popular_store.
But on the "else" url and uri->segment(2) == 'aboutus" mentioned above its showing perfect (only 1 meta)

Awaiting openion...

Comment: try to print both the value and check what exactly they're holding then put a condition.

Comment: after removing else its working fine, dont know what the issue is with "else"

Comment: use if elseif else statement